# OLEDragDrop Event working with compiled exe but not when debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

We're using OLEDragDrop Event in one of our bigger products and have stumbled upon a strange issue. On my machine, if I build the application and run the exe-file, the application sees a drag-drop-event and I can drag a file from the desktop to the program and it saves it and does what it should do. However, when I go into debug-mode, this same function does not work. All I get is an icon-switch to the icon that indicates that I can't release the file "on top" of this program.

My co-worker has the same code, the exact same code from the same revision, and every other project-related setting is exactly the same. But he gets the expected behaviour from the application when debugging. The only reasonable guess we do have is that he hasn't applied the ~300mb security update for visual studio 2010 sp1. I'm right now setting up a virtual machine to check this out and will update when I know if it does indeed work without that update.

Has anyone else had a problem related to this one? Anything that could lead me on the right track I would be eternally grateful for.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio as an Administrator? If so that may be the problem.

Comment: Thank you. That solved it. Post a reply and I'll mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to drag onto the application if Visual Studio is running as an administrator.

Comment: It's something Windows does to protect the elevation barrier. Otherwise lower-privileged applications could interact with higher-privileged ones indirectly.